How can I share TypeScript types between my Node.js/Express backend and Vite-React frontend for deployment?
I am working on a project with a Node.js/Express backend and a Vite-React frontend. I want to share TypeScript types between the backend and frontend. How can I set up my project and build process to share TypeScript types between the backend and frontend effectively?
When I try to do so. An error pops up that states I can't refer something that is outside of the current tsconfig file.

It's unknown how the projects are related in filesystem. You can make it a separate package hosted at git (no npm publishing needed). Or consider it virtual package and alias it in tsconfig "paths" from local FS. Since these are types only, there's no need to care about importing at runtime

You could use Swagger (openAPI) and https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-typescript to autogenerate the types

Typing only exists during development. It does not exist at runtime. but for development you can just point both one project to a file in another project, or even make the one that "owns" the typing an npm linked dependency so you can import it "the normal way"

You can add the other package as a dev dependency, using a relative path as the target.
"backend": "../backend"
Then import away using ordinary imports. Just ensure you only import types so you don't need the other package available at runtime: you can enforce this by using import type { ... } from 'backend'
